# jQuery show a div when something added to cart, and not before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cart, webshop

i need to view a div that show how much you need to buy more to get free shipping on a webshop.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="l-shopgetmore panel-success">Køb for yderligere DKK 1000.00 og få fragtfri levering.</div>
```

and at the bottom of the shop there is:

```
<div class="frifragt" style="display: none;">1000</div>
<div class="priceInCart" style="display: none;">0</div>
```

The 0 in "priceInCart" is actually a snippet of code that checks if there is something in cart and displays id here. In this case the cart is empty.

The css:

```
.l-shopgetmore {
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}


.panel-success {
    background-color: #CAEEF7;
    border-color: #08BFED;
    color: #08BFED;
}
```

So my jQuery code looks like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(j) {

    var start   = 999,
    getFirstNum = jQuery('.frifragt').text(),
    getSecNum   = jQuery('.priceInCart').text(),
    diff        = Number(getFirstNum) - Number(getSecNum),
    getDiscont  = jQuery('.priceInCart').text()

var getAmount = jQuery('.priceInCart').text();

if(getAmount != '0') {

    if(start > getDiscont) {
        jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').html('K&oslash;b for yderligere DKK ' + diff.toFixed(2) + ' og f&aring; fragtfri levering.');
    } else {
        jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').hide();
    }
} 
});
```

The last line

```
jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').hide();
```

is not working.

I need the jQuery to display div with the class ".l-shopgetmore" only when somone puts something in the cart.

Comment: can you put a working example in a fiddle?

Comment: Is there an HTML element that shows when something is added to the cart? An `<li>` perhaps? Or a `<div>` with a particular class that shows it's a cart item? If you can identify a DOM element then your jQuery `if` statement can also look for the existence of the newly created cart element and then trigger the rest of the `if`...

Comment: where is the code for adding to the cart? thats where you'd want the jquery to show/hide etc

Comment: shouldn't u be adding an else statement if `getAmount == '0'`

Comment: You can actually see the webshop here if it helps:

Comment: http://www.hojlund.dk/?templateview=template003_1_copy

Comment: Hope it does't confuse you that the shop is in danish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(j) {
    var frifragt = jQuery('.frifragt');
    var priceInCart = jQuery('.priceInCart');
    var diff = Number(frifragt.text()) - Number(priceInCart.text());
    jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').html('K&oslash;b for yderligere DKK ' + diff.toFixed(2) + ' og f&aring; fragtfri levering.');
    jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').hide();
     setInterval(function(){
       if(jQuery('.priceInCart').text() > 0 || jQuery('.priceInCart').text() < 1000)
          jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').show();
       else
          jQuery('.l-shopgetmore').hide();
     }, '600');


});
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. :/ i copied/paste your code. but it only hides the message, no matter what.

Comment: Cool it kinda worked now. but when there is more than 1000 kr. in cart eg. 1200 kr. then it shows -200 kr. in the message.

Comment: it should just hide it when the cart hits 1000 kr.

Comment: Edited, now when +1000 it hide again